# The reciprocal of $t$-distributed random variable

Tags: distributions, probability

How is $1/T$ distributed if $T$ follows a [Student's $t$-distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution)?

Comment: With 1 df, it is a $t$-distribution *with 1 df :)

Comment: What if $n > 2$?

Comment: Have you tried deriving it from the definition of the Student t distribution?  The calculations are simple.

Comment: I tried but couldn't figure out. I need to check how functions of r.v.'s are considered.

Comment: If it was homework I answered to fast. I’ll expand my "one can show" in my answer.

Comment: To generalize the first comment by @Elvis ever-so-slightly: Note that, for general df $\nu$, if $T \sim t_\nu$, then $T^2 \sim F_{1,\nu}$ and so $T^{-2} \sim F_{\nu,1}$. Elvis' first comment is then recovered immediately via the symmetry of the $t$-distribution.

Comment: @cardinal Thanks for this comment, I didn’t thought of this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One can show that if $X$ has density $f(t)$, then $Y = 1/X$ has density $g(t) = {1\over t^2} f\left( {1\over t} \right)$ (for $t\ne0$).

The density of $T$ with $k$ degrees of freedom is 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{k+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})}\frac{1}{(1+\frac{t^2}{k})^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}$$
so the density of $1 \over T$ is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{k\pi}}\frac{\Gamma(\frac{k+1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})}\frac{1}{t^2(1+\frac{1}{kt^2})^{\frac{k+1}{2}}}.$$

Note that for $k = 1$ this is the same density (in this case $t$ is the quotient of two iid centered gaussian variables).

Here is the allure of this density for $k=1, 2, 30$. As whuber says in the comments when $k>1$ it is bimodal, and all moments diverge.

[image]

**Edit** How do you show with elementary tools $g(t) = {1\over t^2} f\left( {1\over t} \right)$ ?

One possible solution is to first verify (draw a graph) that :
$$\mathbb P(Y\le t) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\mathbb P\left(X \ge {1\over t} \right) + \mathbb P(X \le 0) & \mbox{ if } t> 0 \\
\mathbb P(X \le 0) & \mbox{ if } t= 0 \\
\mathbb P(X\le 0) - \mathbb P\left(X \le {1\over t} \right) & \mbox{ if } t< 0 \\
\end{array}\right.$$

Using this you will easily find how to express the cdf of $Y$ in terms of the cdf of $X$ ; derive this expression to obtain the density.

Comment: (+1) Note that the reciprocal distribution is *bimodal* when $k\gt 1$.  All the moments diverge (for any $k$).

Comment: You’re right, I’ll add a graph, it’s a matter of five minutes.

Comment: A nit pick: the bimodality kicks in as soon as $k$ exceeds 1; e.g., it's there for $k=1.01$. (Student's t is defined for all real $k\gt 0$, not just positive integral $k$.)

Comment: @whuber yes! and the limit in 0 would deserve some special attention when $k<1<2$. No time now...

Comment: That limit is $0$ because the original Student t distribution decays faster than $t^{-2}$ as $t\to\pm\infty$ for $1\lt k$.

Comment: hum, yes, don't know what I was thinking to